# save a PDF file to a directory using mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a question regarding the PDF files.I have written the code in order to open a PDF, i manage to output the context in the browser but i want also this PDF file to be saved in a directory.

Does anyone know how i will do it?

I can post the code if you think this will be helpful for you.

Thank you in advance,
Sachin

Answer (score 12):

Quote from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574193/php-mpdf-save-file-as-pdf):

> Docs state that the first argument of Output() is the file path,
>   second is the savng mode - you need to set it to 'F'.

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
```

Comment: This solution saves the .pdf file into the root of the application (ie in CodeIgniter, it will be saved in the root directory together with `application`, `system`)

Comment: Not at home to test, but could you use  `$mpdf->Output('../../filename.pdf','F');`

Comment: you saved my whole day .. thanks