# PHP mPDF save file as PDF

Tags: php, pdf, save, mpdf

I have a page which uses mPDF which when you run displays a PDF in the browser, it can also be saved from here as a PDF no problem. What I would like to happen is when the page is run and generates a PDF that the page is saved as a PDF on the server.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/seo-check/lib/WSAclient.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/seo-check/lib/WSAParser.php';

$reportID= $_GET['reportid'];

$WSAclient = new WSAclient(WSA_USER_ID,WSA_API_KEY);

$result=$WSAclient->viewReport($reportID,WSA_SUBSCRIPTION_ID,'xml','EN');

unset($WSAclient);

ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PDF Report</title>
<!--Add your CSS here-->
</head>
<body>    
<?php  
echo WSAParser::viewReportResponse($result);
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$HTMLoutput = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


//Convert HTML 2 PDF by using MPDF PHP library
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/seo-check/lib/MPDF/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($HTMLoutput);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Like I said this outputs the PDF fine but could someone tell me how to save as a PDF?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The [mPDF docs](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) state that the first argument of `Output()` is the file path, second is the saving mode - you need to set it to `'F'`.

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but changing it to D instead of F did! What do they mean?

Comment: D - send to browser and force download, F - save to file. Docs link I provided explains it.

Comment: What are other options and what is the meaning of `F`?

Comment: D - means Download, F - means File-save only, as T.Todua mentioned in his answer. It perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
$mpdf->Output('my_filename.pdf','D');
```

because:

`D` - means Download
   `F` - means File-save only

Comment: Saved me some time with this one.  Thanks!

Comment: And `I` means display on browser

Answer (score 26):

This can be done like this. It worked fine for me. And also set the directory permissions to 777 or 775 if not set.

```
ob_clean();
$mpdf->Output('directory_name/pdf_file_name.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: This is a better answer as it specifies how to save it to a directory. `+1`

Comment: this worked for me , also make sure you specfiy the path of the out put file

Comment: @kinsleykajiva. Can you explain where can we get the output path from?  This is how my code looks like but the file doesnt get saved on the server      
  `        
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($echomsg);
       $_Globals['SITE_ROOT']=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
        $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $_Globals['SITE_ROOT']);
        $src= "../wp-content/themes/krystal/files/filename.pdf";
       $mpdf->Output($src,'F');
         $msg= "<iframe src='$src' width='500px' height='700px'></iframe>"; 
      echo $msg;  `

Comment: @Far have you set the folder permission that allows your PHP to make writes to the folder if your using Linux? if that's so check if there is any data in the .temp folder.

Answer (score 4):

The [Go trough this link](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html)  state that the first argument of `Output()` is the file path, second is the saving mode - you need to set it to `'F'`.

```
 $upload_dir = public_path(); 
             $filename = $upload_dir.'/testing7.pdf'; 
              $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
              //$test = $mpdf->Image($pro_image, 0, 0, 50, 50);

              $html ='<h1> Project Heading </h1>';
              $mail = ' <p> Project Heading </p> ';
              
              $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
              $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
              $mpdf->WriteHTML($mail);

              $mpdf->Output($filename,'F'); 
              $mpdf->debug = true;
```

Example :

```
 $mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Example #2

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

// Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
```